How to import multiple GIT projects into Eclipse workspace
I have a number of projects that I am trying to consolidate into a single Eclipse workspace.  Some of the projects use Git.  I would appreciate some tips on the best way to do this.
I would expect the workspace folder to be filled like:
<workspace>
-->Project 1
-->Project 2
-->Project 3

"Project 1" may be a git project, where in its current location, it is on disk like
<current folder>
-->Project 1
-->.git (for Project 1)

In this case, if I import Project 1 into the new workspace using the Eclipse import command and browse to the Project 1 directory, I can import the project.  But it does not import/copy the git information.
In general, is there a better way of doing this?  Keeping in mind that multiple projects may have a similar organization in their current location?
Thanks!

File > Open Projects from File System... with the root directory of the Git repository. Or in the Git Repositories view, right-click the Git repository and choose Import Projects...

How exactly are you importing the project? What does it contain (Is it a Java project? Is it using a build tool?) What exactly happens when importing it?
